# Electron: Modificar tamaño de un icono Tray

Tags: electron

Me gustaría saber si es posible modificar el tamaño de un icono Tray de Electron. No quiero editar el icono vía editor de imagen...
cuando defino un elemento de Tray, tenemos opción `icon` que nos permite poner un icono, sin embargo me aparece demasiado grande ya que su tamaño original es de 256X256 y me gustaría que se viese más pequeño en la lista de menú de Tray

También me gustaría saber si es posible editar un label del Tray (via ID, por ejemplo) desde otro archivo

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si alguien se ecuentra en el mismo problema, ya he dado con la solución,
al generar el menu, hay que hacerle un resize de la siguiente manera:

```
    var contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'Item1',
      icon: nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath).resize({width: 16, height: 16})
    }
  ]);
```